# How to scroll down to the bottom of an inner scroll bar using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make the auto scroller work for the "details panel" on the left side of this website but I can't seem to make it work. I've tried looking for `iframes` as well but I can't find any.

Here is my code:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://kart.1881.no/?query=1010')
time.sleep(8)

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'main-panel-scroll')

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

while True:
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
            time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            if new_height == last_height:
                break
            else:
                last_height = new_height
                continue


time.sleep(10)
```

I have tried to use different elements to make the scroller "focus" on the left panel using various methods like xpath, class name, etc but none of them allows me to scroll. The code closes out without errors.

It doesn't look like it uses iframes either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the complete solution:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

driver = Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://kart.1881.no/?query=1010')

scroll_bar = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search_result')))

flag = True
last_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", scroll_bar)
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

while flag:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", scroll_bar)
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    new_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", scroll_bar)

    if new_height == last_height:
        flag = False
    else:
        last_height = new_height
```

steps followed:

1. First, we wait for the scroll-bar web element to get visibly located/loaded on the page and assign it to a variable `scroll_bar`
2. Next, we get the current height of this `scroll_bar` and assign it to a variable `last_height`.
3. start looping and in each iteration, scroll down to the bottom of the scroll bar, take a pause, get the height of the scroll bar, and assign it to a variable `new_height` and check if the `new_height == last_height`, break out of the loop(`flag=Flase`) otherwise, update the variable `last_height` with `new_height` and repeat this step until the `if condition` is True.

I hope this solves your problem.